# how to reduce vendor.js file in angular 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular9

I'm using Angular 9, when I try to run my project using ng serve then I'm getting **Java Heap out memory Error**  but using **export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"** this command the project is working but my **vendor.js** size is getting **43.3Mb**. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This file includes all libraries that you added to your project. If you build your app on production mode it'll be much lower.

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: @kavindra using this command I'm getting same **java heap out memory error**